# How to keep the old picture value that have uploaded to database with input type file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have to views one for Create and the other for edit a record in database.
The record contain picture... My problem is with editing .
every time I want to edit a record I must reselect the picture again.
How can I make the controller keep the old value??

I tried to give the input a default value but I discovered that I can't

```
public ActionResult Edit(Carousel carousel,HttpPostedFileBase picture)
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), picture.FileName);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                picture.SaveAs(path);
                carousel.Picture = picture.FileName;
                db.Entry(carousel).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(carousel);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not keep image with `input type="file"`, you need display image with `<img src="@Model.Image" />`

In cshtml edit file:

```
<input type="file" name="image" />
<img src="@Model.Image" alt="my image" />
```

Comment: sorry you misunderstanding  me .... how can I update my record without reselect the image .... I cant do that

Comment: You can not do like that, you need reselect image, i tried it before